# Using Excel, how to trap the copy/paste object?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel, copy-paste

One can copy/paste into and out of Excel.  It seems like there is a basic `\n` and `\t` tab protocol that is being followed.

- How exactly could I `peek inside` to see the mechanics?
- Do those mechanics change on OS as copy/paste is an OS event?
- How do they change in a web setting (e.g., copy from Excel 2010 to a cloud version)?

Fundamentally, this question arises because within Excel if you copy/paste it will update the REFERENCES of your formulas.  That tells me that under the hood, it captured during copy and paste the attributes of the CELLS?

- How to `peek inside` the attributes of the CELLS being copied and pasted (the FORMULAS)?
- Is it encrypted so it can't be viewed?

### Question:  Using Excel, how to trap the copy/paste object?

Comment: What exactly do you want to copy? Do you mean you want manually to copy the formulas or to copy the values from the formula? I mean  if C1 = B1 + B2 do you want to copy 'C1 = B1 + B2' or you want to copy the value in C1, e.g. 3 (if B1 = 1 & B2 = 2)

Comment: If I built an `external` web app, and someone COPY/PASTED cells from EXCEL into that APP, I could know "WHERE THE CELLS" were located, and PROPERTIES/FUNCTIONS on each.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that in Windows, you can use the <kbd>Start+V</kbd> shortcut to see the content of the clipboard? This is accessible throughout your entire Windows session, not only Excel.

... or are you looking for a way to access this information from inside Excel? In that case, you might need to extend your VBA with following reference:

[image]